# Python raw multicast

Tags: python, networking, multicast

I'm trying to listen to multicast trafic with Python. I try to listen to decode carp protocol, so it's raw trafic not UDP. But I don't receive any data.

If, on the same host, I use an appication listening for the carp trafic (ucarp), the application see the trafic, so it should be working.

Here is the code I'm using:

```python
import socket
import struct

MCAST_GRP = '224.0.0.18'

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, 112)

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

print("waiting for data...")
print(s.recvfrom(10))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, this code is working. The network setup I was using, not. I don't know why this was working with ucarp and not python.

The setup which was not working was a libvirt host running the python and a kvm VM with openbsd sending the carp.

The working setup is two VM, one openbsd sending the carp and one Debian/Linux running the python code.